# Incorrect file upload path in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am very beginner in Laravel.

I use Laravel 5.8 in my project.

I use this component: CkEditor + https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager .

When uploading files, they get to upload to storage/app. I would like them to be available from the website and located in the folder: public/upload

My lfm.php file:

```
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Routing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'use_package_routes'       => true,

    // // Use relative paths (without domain)
    // 'relative_paths'           => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Multi-User Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'allow_multi_user'         => false,

    'allow_share_folder'       => true,



    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Folder Names
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    // Flexible way to customize client folders accessibility
    // If you want to customize client folders, publish tag="lfm_handler"
    // Then you can rewrite userField function in App\Handler\ConfigHandler class
    // And set 'user_field' to App\Handler\ConfigHandler::class
    // Ex: The private folder of user will be named as the user id.
    'user_folder_name'         => UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Handlers\ConfigHandler::class,
    'base_directory' => 'public',
    'shared_folder_name'       => 'upload',
    'thumb_folder_name'        => 'thumbs',
    'files_folder_name' => 'file',
    'images_folder_name' => 'img',



    'folder_categories'        => [
        'file'  => [
            'folder_name'  => 'upload',
            'startup_view' => 'grid',
            'max_size'     => 50000, // size in KB
            'valid_mime'   => [
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/gif',
                'image/svg+xml',
            ],
        ],
        'image' => [
            'folder_name'  => 'photos',
            'startup_view' => 'list',
            'max_size'     => 50000, // size in KB
            'valid_mime'   => [
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/gif',
                'image/svg+xml',
                'application/pdf',
                'text/plain',
            ],
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Upload / Validation
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'disk'                     => 'public',

    'rename_file'              => false,

    'alphanumeric_filename'    => false,

    'alphanumeric_directory'   => true,

    'should_validate_size'     => false,

    'should_validate_mime'     => true,

    // permissions to be set when create a new folder or when it creates automatically with thumbnails
    'create_folder_mode'       => 0755,

    // permissions to be set on file upload.
    'create_file_mode'         => 0644,

    // If true, it will attempt to chmod the file after upload
    'should_change_file_mode'  => true,

    // behavior on files with identical name
    // setting it to true cause old file replace with new one
    // setting it to false show `error-file-exist` error and stop upload
    'over_write_on_duplicate'  => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Thumbnail
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    // If true, image thumbnails would be created during upload
    'should_create_thumbnails' => false,

    // Create thumbnails automatically only for listed types.
    'raster_mimetypes'         => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
    ],

    'thumb_img_width'          => 200,

    'thumb_img_height'         => 200,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | jQuery UI options
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'resize_aspectRatio'       => false,

    'resize_containment'       => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | File Extension Information
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'file_type_array'          => [
        'pdf'  => 'Adobe Acrobat',
        'doc'  => 'Microsoft Word',
        'docx' => 'Microsoft Word',
        'xls'  => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'xlsx' => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'zip'  => 'Archive',
        'gif'  => 'GIF Image',
        'jpg'  => 'JPEG Image',
        'jpeg' => 'JPEG Image',
        'png'  => 'PNG Image',
        'ppt'  => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
        'pptx' => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
    ],

    'file_icon_array'          => [
        'pdf'  => 'fa-file-pdf-o',
        'doc'  => 'fa-file-word-o',
        'docx' => 'fa-file-word-o',
        'xls'  => 'fa-file-excel-o',
        'xlsx' => 'fa-file-excel-o',
        'zip'  => 'fa-file-archive-o',
        'gif'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'jpg'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'jpeg' => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'png'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'ppt'  => 'fa-file-powerpoint-o',
        'pptx' => 'fa-file-powerpoint-o',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | php.ini override
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These values override your php.ini settings before uploading files
    | Set these to false to ingnore and apply your php.ini settings
    |
    | Please note that the 'upload_max_filesize' & 'post_max_size'
    | directives are not supported.
     */
    'php_ini_overrides'        => [
        'memory_limit' => '256M',
    ],
];
```

The traditional upload works correctly (uploads files to the public / upload directory):

```
$file->move(public_path($path), $uniqueName . '.' . $extension);
```

How can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to follow the framework guidelines, its the best practice while you're developing using on it.

For reference, codes example you can find anything in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem

Edit:

To save in public folder is the same logic, try `Storage::disk('public')->put('filename', $file_content);` The `Storage::disk()` method you can point the directory you want to put the file, but this is in the 5.8, I don't know what version what you're using but I guess this is works since 5.2/3, check out and let us know it worked.

Comment: The standard function for Laravela works correctly. Files are saved to public/upload :) Problem is with Laravel file manager. This component save files to storage/app  - not to public/upload:(

Comment: To save in public folder is the same logic, try `Storage::disk('public')->put('filename', $file_content);`

The `Storage::disk()` method you can point the directory you want to put the file, but this is in the 5.8, I don't know what version what you're using but I guess this is works since 5.2/3, check out and let us know if worked.